# Regarding response and request in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I have downloaded one application in which i am unable to find where the hell database operation is made
thing is 
there is one url of localhost 
For eg:- localhosttest/search/products
and code is written to send xml as data for POST
and then in return response comes from my db.
But I am unable to find any select,insert,update query in either code or in sql in this mvc4 application..how can i find that.any help would be great
Thanks
Code is something like this

```
 protected T Execute<T>(Product request) where T : new()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            T response = default(T);


                RestfulQuery query = new RestfulQuery(string.Format("{0}/{1}", _asUrl, request.Resource));

                string result = string.Empty;
                string mimeType = "application/xml";

                switch (request.Method)
                {
                    case Method.GET:
                        query.Method("GET")
                          .MimeType(mimeType);
                        break;
                    case Method.POST:
                        query.Method("POST")
                          .MimeType(mimeType)
                          .WriteParam(request.Data);
                        break;
                    case Method.PUT:
                        query.Method("PUT")
                          .MimeType(mimeType)
                          .WriteParam(request.Data);
                        break;
                    case Method.DELETE:
                        query.Method("DELETE")
                          .MimeType(mimeType)
                          .WriteParam(request.Data);
                        break;

                }


                result = query.Execute();

                response = SerializerHelper.Deserialize<T>(result);

            }


            return response; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: For sure you have a third party tool. All db operations are done via `RestfulQuery`. You need to investigate that. If it's not a third party tool and if it's another project you have access to then that's wonderful. If not then nothing you can do about it but learn how to consume it.

Comment: But how I mean there is one url on which i am posting data in xml format and it gives response to me..but I want to find that from where and which code that response comes from my database..I want to find that

Comment: Are you saying `localhosttest/search/products` calls that `Execute` method for all types of operation (e.e. PUT, POST, GET, DELETE)? It doesn't make sense. Better to edit you question and provide more info.  It might be flagged as not a real question.

Comment: On localhost/search/products...I am sending one xml as request using Advance Rest Client of chrome addon and it gives me response but i want to know how did I get the response.since in my project no such select statements are der